# How to show Modal on click in span using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script for Jquery to show the Modal:

```
$('.cssbuttongo').click(
function() 
{
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

This is where .cssbuttongo work in :

```
 <span class="cssbuttongo">Login</span>
                                        <span class="cssbuttongo">Register</span>
```

This is where i call my Modal:

```
           <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
            <!--    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> !-->
                <h4 class="modal-title">Authentication</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
....
```

Don't show anything in click.

How to fix this??

> ```
>     <script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
>
>     <script src="/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
>      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
>     <script src="/js/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
>     <script src="/js/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="/js/plugins.js"></script>
>     <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
> ```
>
> ```
>     <!--- Google Maps ! ---->
>
>     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAZSFaWC5HQA0ixyI-QXBE5EMAMnTCaY80"></script>
>       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.24/gmaps.js"></script>
>
>     <script src="/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="/js/login.js"></script>
>     <script src="/js/ajaxforms.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: try to use event delegation , change `$('.cssbuttongo').click(` to `$('.cssbuttongo').on('click'`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam It's not working, sorry

Comment: are there any errors on console ?

Comment: what provides the `modal()` functionality?  `jQuery 1.11` doesnt alone, and you are not using `jQueryUI` that I see.

Comment: i agree @NappingRabbit

Comment: @NappingRabbit what you are telling to me it is that i dont need jquery 1.11?

Comment: no, you likely do.  you do for the `.on()` or `.click()` functionality.  I am suggesting that it does not provide your `modal()` functionality.  does one of the other loaded libraries provide it?

Comment: if you replace `$('#myModal').modal('show');` with `alert('this thing')` or `console.log('this thing')` does it verify it is running to that point?

Comment: @NappingRabbit not working , don't show any value in the console.

Comment: ok well that helps.  are you certain that the targets (the spans to be clicked) are loaded before the javascript runs?  i.e. wrapped in `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: It's imported before footer @NappingRabbit

Comment: as long as you call the `.click()` or `.on('click',` bit AFTER the spans are loaded, that is fine.

Comment: @NappingRabbit i have updated the post, see the modal html/botstrap

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i have updated the post, see the modal html/botstrap

Comment: Why you use my answer to fix your question? and put my answer content on your question description? don't be a troll please...

Comment: This isn't the way of how it works SO... You don't copy the answer we give you on your question description and say I solve it! Please erase the "solution" of the question description, leave the question as it was. That way other people that need helps with something similar will find the solution on the answer section and not on the question description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it, **You don't have any modal** on your html code, I mean you don't have the modal structure, modal structure needs header, body and footer to be able to work. You have to define all of them.

I fixed it. Look at my snippet:

```js
$('.cssbuttongo').click(function (){
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" class="cssbuttongo">Register</span>

<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog">

<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Cssbutton Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello I'm your modal!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

You will not see the button styles because you didn't add any css with this **cssbuttongo class** and this is why you will only see the **"register"** word. If you click on **"register"** now you see the modal. Hope it helps

Comment: @OlympikeSoft hahaha you saw my answer and then use it to fix the question (edit it)? Nice one. It seems like a troll to me...

Comment: thing is, since it is bootstrap you likely need the `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal"` parts too

Comment: @NappingRabbit Yeah. He didn't have any of that. I don't know how he did expect to get a modal without having any declared... And the guy just took my answer and copied to the content question (description)...

Comment: @JulioPérez i will see if it's work but it could be working like you said :)